# Idiomatic way of checking length of input is 0 when input can be None

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def func(ids=None):
  try:
    assert len(ids) == 0
    return {}
  except(TypeError, AssertionError):
    # do some stuff and return {}
```

I'm not sure if this is idiomatic because I'm using the except clause to handle both the case where `ids` is None (the default value) and when `len(ids) > 0`. Is there an idiomatic way of writing this?

`ids` can be a list, tuple, or perhaps other container with `len`

Comment: What should happens if `ids` is `None`?

Comment: Not to mention, aren't those all falsey values anyway? Why even bother going through any of those lengths when you can just `if not ids`?

Comment: @xTerrene That depends on whether None should give a different response to, for example, an empty list. OP hasn't explained that. VTC as needs more clarity

Comment: I used specifically those checks be because they explcitely tell you what is happening inside the program. @xTerrene `not` calls the `__bool__` method, which can be defined differently between different types (i.e authors of external classes may feel that a particular object should be considered false under different conditions than what the user expects). Also, @chepner not everyone has their static type checkers configured properly. If you don't have something like pylance on stict mode in your editing environment, annotations won't stop types from being incorrectly passed into functions.

Comment: Note to my orginal comment: apperently `typing` is deprecated, so rather use `collections.abc.Sized` than `typing.Sized`

Comment: @mozway It should do what is done in the OP, i.e., do whatever is in the except clause

Comment: @chepner the issue is the `else` logic is whatever would be in the `except` block. I just didn't know how to properly route it there without using an assertion and catching the `AssertionError`

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(ids=None):
    if (ids is not None) and (not ids):
        return {}
    # do some stuff and return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this.

You can avoid the reality that `not None == True` and `not int(0) == True` (in any form, len etc.)

```
def func(ids=True):
  if not ids:
    assert len(ids) == 0
    return {}
  elif ids:
    # do some stuff and return {}
  else:
    raise YouDidAllWrong
```

Answer (score -1):

I would restructure you function to the below:

```
from collections.abc import Sized
def func(ids:Sized|None=None):
    if (ids is None):
        pass # do something

    # optional type safely, not required if you have a static type checker
    if not isinstance(ids,Sized): raise TypeError()

    ids_len = len(ids)
    if (ids_len==0):
        pass # do something
```

Comment: Don't use typing.Sized. Use collections.abc.Sized. Deprecated since 3.12

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot. I am used to writting code for old versions of python (my university uses Python 3.8) so I am not up to data on all the latest practices in the newest version of python.